# Can grub move boot folders back to root?

Tags: 14.04, boot, command-line, grub2

Accidentally copied everything and moved it to another folder. Can you move it back? What are some ways to fix this?

[image: terminal output]

[higher resolution image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NknRX.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do-

If you have a Ubuntu or any other linux distro live usb drive (if you have another pc, make a live session usb ASAP) boot from that usb. Close the installation window and fire up a terminal. Run this command: `sudo apt-get upgrade nautilus`. Then run `gksu nautilus`. Using the file explorer, revert the changes you have made.

Or alternatively you can run ubuntu boot repair. To install boot repair, run command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then select recommended repair.

Let me know if you had any luck.

---

> *One machine can do the work of fifty ordinary men. No machine can do the work of one extraordinary man. -Elbert Hubbard*

Comment: I'm booting from live cd. But I can't sudo apt get install gksu I have to enable the component called 'universe'.

Comment: Okay open "software and updates" from apps. Go to Ubuntu updates tab. Tick the second option (community maintained free and open source software (universre))"

Comment: Or to enable universe you can run command `sudo add-apt-repository universe`

Comment: I did that and it's already ticked. But maybe I'm not explaining correctly. I have a usb ubuntu and i'm using try ubuntu without installing. for some reason those commands don't work. unable to locate package gksu after running sudo apt-get install gksu.

Comment: Strange try these
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install nautilus`

`sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: No doesn't work..

Comment: Make sure you add these one by one and press enter after each command

Comment: Cool it works, but it says I don't have root permissions to change the folders.

Comment: Is nautilus installed? If it is you have to manually open it through a terminal by running the command `gksu nautilus`. This opens a file browser which gives you access to root permissions.

Comment: Nice. I added sudo in front and it works, let me try rebooting now!

Comment: Oh my goodness. You saved my life. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how exactly you "moved everything", you may try to boot from the installation media, and then in the live session mount the root filesystem on `/mnt` and move everything back where it was. Try and see if it works.

(The important thing is whether you moved the files and directories preserving ownership and permissions or not. If the move did not preserve ownership and permissions then I don't see how you can recover.)